# Is there something like -webkit-column-gap to flow text in rows to simulate "pages"?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm trying to build an approximation of something like the Google Docs editor where text that user edits can flow from page to page, vertically, like this:

[image: Google Docs text flowing from page to page]

My best idea for how to do something like this, up until now, has been to continually measure the size of the content in a page's container, and if it exceeds the size allotted to the page, programmatically move pieces of text to the 2nd page until the content in the 1st page fits again.

Short of building a Google Docs-like layout engine (a la traditional word processors), I haven't come up with anything better, but then I stumbled across `-webkit-column-gap` (obviously will only work on WebKit, I'm okay with that at the moment).

Using `-webkit-column-gap`, I'm able to flow text from column to column; if I put the text in a `contenteditable` div, it almost approaches the effect I'm looking for - as I type more, content automatically flows from "page" to "page", except the "pages" are all side-by-side in columns, like this:

[image: Text flowing from column to column]

Here's the HTML I'm using for this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
          <title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="book.css" type="text/css"/>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="body">
             <div class="content" contenteditable="true">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dictum tempor suscipit. Donec nec mauris leo, in blandit lacus. Nunc a condimentum dui. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin sagittis porta leo fermentum faucibus. Ut porta, sem sit amet placerat interdum, odio enim ornare nisi, vitae rhoncus lacus erat quis leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc accumsan iaculis nisi, et lacinia turpis fringilla eu. Aliquam adipiscing posuere dui. Integer vel nulla purus. Praesent at eros leo, at facilisis augue. Aliquam aliquam vulputate lacinia. Cras vel leo urna, sed commodo augue. Nullam fringilla eleifend augue ac tincidunt. Maecenas quis velit tortor, sit amet tempor quam.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum quam tortor, ornare nec rutrum at, eleifend sed odio. Nam dignissim erat a velit interdum a egestas enim ullamcorper. Nulla sit amet massa quis metus congue tincidunt id vitae felis. Praesent at odio a ante molestie viverra. Aenean fringilla nisi sed urna sodales feugiat aliquet diam vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus facilisis ultricies est nec consequat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam ac consectetur mi. Vestibulum volutpat rutrum urna, eu vestibulum sem posuere in. Cras volutpat lacinia lorem, vitae commodo quam congue a. Praesent vestibulum placerat nisi ac bibendum. Aenean nec urna quam, id dapibus neque. Quisque elit tellus, condimentum sed semper quis, vulputate a mi.</p>

                <p>Sed ac turpis sed felis condimentum sodales. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus porttitor scelerisque vulputate. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas pellentesque rutrum eleifend. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sed lacus nec velit lobortis pellentesque. Suspendisse in neque lacus. Proin vel risus ullamcorper orci condimentum convallis. Duis quis lectus eu nibh bibendum feugiat. Etiam dapibus dapibus nisl ut interdum. Pellentesque sollicitudin sollicitudin dapibus.</p>

                <p>Nam interdum lobortis augue eleifend suscipit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus pharetra, orci vitae luctus pretium, lectus purus blandit magna, a viverra sapien metus quis libero. Morbi scelerisque sem sed turpis gravida ultricies. Mauris in fringilla risus. Sed non enim vel ipsum aliquet consequat non ut metus. Ut tincidunt ante eget est pretium lobortis tempor erat interdum. Proin faucibus justo odio, sed accumsan erat. Fusce ac risus lacus.</p>

                <p>Etiam condimentum, ligula nec lobortis commodo, lectus sem ultrices ante, vel eleifend lacus tortor eu felis. Vivamus euismod imperdiet libero, sed blandit magna faucibus id. Nulla auctor venenatis suscipit. Integer massa nisi, eleifend nec tincidunt id, aliquam nec metus. Nam ac elit vitae mauris condimentum viverra. Proin pharetra facilisis odio ac facilisis. Pellentesque et nisi malesuada justo pellentesque aliquam ut nec purus. Sed iaculis, nibh at ultricies euismod, turpis magna vulputate libero, non pretium tellus erat ut justo. Sed placerat mattis neque, a tempus purus aliquam in. Sed egestas dapibus magna. Quisque iaculis dictum mauris, non iaculis massa lacinia sit amet. Proin congue quam sed augue mollis volutpat. Morbi velit libero, venenatis ut commodo vel, mollis ut erat.</p>
             </div>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

and the CSS:

```
html {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    -webkit-column-width: 200px;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Now this is all well and good, but what I'd really like is for the "pages" to stack vertically, like the Google Docs example above.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `column-gap` property is a standard CSS feature (from [CSS Multi-column layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-gap) spec), which works across all modern browsers. You just need to use the version without the -webkit- prefix for IE and Opera, and -moz- prefix for Firefox.

However, there is no feature in the multi-column spec for pages. There is a [paged media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) specification, which would do what you want, but it only works for print and print preview.

Opera has a proposal for paging outside of print, which works well with multi-column. This uses the `@paged` at-rule and the `paged-x`, `paged-x-controls` `paged-y`, or `paged-y-controls` values on the overflow property. However, the pages are more like that of the iPad, where there are paging control to go to the next/previous page, such as by swiping or pressing a button. This currently only works in Opera. See this [demonstration and explanation](http://people.opera.com/howcome/2011/reader/).

You could use CSS Regions to achieve what you are looking for, but it currently only works in IE10 (and requires an iframe with that implementation). There is also an experimental WebKit implementation. See the [CSS Regions spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-regions/) and info on the [IE10 implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).